# Update a value of a key value pair in a nested array in C#

Tags: c#, api, automation

I have the following json

```
  {"audit_entry": {
    "where_uri": "test.com/service/apps/171f0841-825b-4964-8f8c-0869650f14a6",
    "why_uri": "test.com/service/reference/reasons_for_change/43545kjhjhkj0869650f14a6",
    "who_uri": "test.com/service/users/4977dae1-a307-425f-980c-53413fef1b0f",
    "when_audited": "2018-11-13T20:20:39+00:00",
    "what_uri": "test.com/service/subjects/1bc67a71-8549-4ab8-9dd9-e44238198860",
    "what_changed": [
        {
            "attribute_name": "birth_year",
            "attribute_value": "1969",
            "attribute_change": null
        },
        {
            "attribute_name": "subject_reference",
            "attribute_value": "dsdsfg",
            "attribute_change": null
        }
        ]
    }
```

I want to be able to change the value of "attribute_value" in the second child of what_changed. i.e. index [1]. I have tried the following code:

```
        JObject jObj = JObject.Parse(jsonText);
        jObj["audit_entry"]["what_changed"]["attribute_name"[1]];
```

But I know I have an issue with syntax.
Any ideas would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: first try to write code whcih would asign every indexer call to variable (you know that `"attribute_name"[1]` is `'t'` ?)

Comment: Here is the documentation on [Getting values by Property Name or Collection Index](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) using `Jobject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the documentation on [Getting values by Property Name or Collection Index](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryingLINQtoJSON.htm) using `JObject`.

You can see the usage of index in the code example :

```
string itemTitle = (string)rss["channel"]["item"][0]["title"];
```

In you code example it should be :

```
var toto = (string)jObj["audit_entry"]["what_changed"][1]["attribute_name"];
```

[Live example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/kLmToT)

You can the use [Modifying JSON](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/ModifyJson.htm) as reference for the modification:

```
jObj["audit_entry"]["what_changed"][1]["attribute_name"] = "New Value";
```